# Trying to run a pack of selenium tests written in java using Jenkins

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

After reading nearly all the posts that it suggests under "Questions with similar titles" (I will continue reading after sending this post) and reading

> - centripetal.ca/blog/2011/02/07/getting-started-with-selenium-and-jenkins/
> - oliverpolden.com/content/setting-automated-selenium-testing-jenkinshudson

and some other posts (I note these two because I think they may be useful to someone) I haven't found an answer to what I need. And now I get to that:

I'm working in a company that uses Jenkins for CI and maven. They have three types of tests ran for the sotware: junit, cactus and selenium. Jenkins has a job to run junit tests. Now they've decided to run the other two types of tests (Cactus and Selenium) using Jenkins. And that's my task. Cactus would be another question I'll ask later (have been banging my head with that one for too long right now). The Selenium tests are written in java and there's a java file that has all the tests as it follows:

```
package com.mycompany.test.dailySanity;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        Test1.class,
        Test2.class,
        Test3.class,
})

public class AllTests {
        /**
         * This is just a place holder.
         * Add All your TestClass one to the list above.
         * NOTE, the TestClasses should be "," separated
         */
}
```

All the information I've found talks about an htmlsuite, but nothing about if the tests are in java (no, exporting them to HTML is not an option). I've tried

> export DISPLAY=":99" && java -jar /path/to/selenium-server.jar
>   -browserSessionReuse -htmlSuite *firefox http://localhost
>   /path/to/my/testsfile/AllTests.java
>   /path/to/my/logfile/SeleniumLog.html

as an "*Execute Shell*" in "*Build*" step in Jenkins job, but it just stays trying something.
 **Console output**

```
09:29:48.508 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 14.2-b01
09:29:48.518 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.18.8-xenU amd64
09:29:48.654 INFO - v2.4.0, with Core v2.4.0. Built from revision 13337
09:29:49.263 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
09:29:49.264 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
09:29:49.269 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
09:29:49.271 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
09:29:49.271 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
09:29:49.337 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@7a187814
09:29:49.337 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
09:29:49.343 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
09:29:49.343 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@67ad77a7
10:51:00.038 INFO - Shutting down...
10:51:00.040 INFO - Stopping Acceptor ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=4444]
```

I assume it does nothing else (waited for 2 hours before aboting it) beacause it's a java file and it requires an html file (*-htmlsuite* is a clue).

To sum up: I need a way to run Selenium tests written in Java and packaged in a java suite on Jenkins.

---

**EDITING**
Ok, I'm not getting anywhere and running out of time. I'm adding more information just in case someone can give me a hand (not that I'm not thankful to Ross). Here goes my selenium_pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <background>true</background>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase -->
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <includes>
                                <include>/path/to/my/tests/AllTests.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run

```
mvn -f selenium_pom.xml integration-test
```

I get the following output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.kana.sem:selenium-test:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 44, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building selenium-test 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ selenium-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /path/to/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ selenium-test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ selenium-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /path/to/resources/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ selenium-test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) @ selenium-test ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ selenium-test ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- selenium-maven-plugin:2.1:start-server (default) @ selenium-test ---
Launching Selenium Server
Waiting for Selenium Server...
[WARNING] OS appears to be Unix and no DISPLAY environment variable has been detected. Browser maybe unable to function correctly. Consider using the selenium:xvfb goal to enable headless operation.
[INFO] User extensions: /localhome/kana/p4/dev/BOT/target/selenium/user-extensions.js
08:05:07,166 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] Java: IBM Corporation 2.3
08:05:07,173 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] OS: Linux 2.6.18.8-xenU x86
08:05:07,184 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] v2.9.0, with Core v2.9.0. Built from revision 14289
08:05:07,273 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
08:05:07,277 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer] Version Jetty/5.1.x
08:05:07,686 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@51fe51fe
08:05:07,687 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
08:05:07,687 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/,/]
08:05:07,688 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
08:05:07,689 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
08:05:07,705 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener] Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
08:05:07,705 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@40e640e6
08:05:07.916 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
Selenium Server started
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default) @ selenium-test ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /path/to/surefire-reports/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 30.387s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 13 08:05:08 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/30M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using perforce, Jenkins, maven3 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga). I'm sure my pom is one of the problems, but got it from internet samples...

---

Thanks (and congratulations to all that have finished reading this post!)

PS: If you also know how to get a report from the Selenium tests that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The `-htmlsuite` option is for something completely different from what you're trying to do.  Don't let it distract you :-)

Your Java code appears to be written so that the tests are executed via JUnit.  That's a very common technique.  I expect all you need to do is make sure the Selenium RC server is running before the tests begin.  Just `java -jar /path/to/selenium-server.jar` and leave it running until at least the end of the last test.  Your tests will contact the server by creating a connection to it, probably by calling `new DefaultSelenium(...)`.

Comment: So I should add 3 Execute Shells steps
- Start the server
- Run the tests
- Stop the server
?
While I get an answer (if possible) I'm trying things, so if I get it to work I'll come back and try to explain it. Anyway, if you can put a complete example it woudl be great.
Last, thanks for taking your time to read a such large post and answering!

Comment: I'm editing my post, so if anyone whish to help re-read, please.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is very well integrated with Maven, so I suggest you concentrate on running the tests using *Maven* rather than Jenkins. You can use the failsafe plugin to run integration tests such as your selenium tests. Jenkins will automatically find the failsafe reports and show a pretty HTML summary. Also, you can test this more easily on your local machine.

Please can you update your post to clarify whether you're using Selenium 1 or 2. `RemoteWebDriver` looks like v2, but your POM shows `selenium-java-client-driver` from 1.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer artbristol.

I'm trying first to make this work in maven on my local machine. But it is required to be automated, so I'll try to move it to Jenkins after.

Related to your question about Selenium 1 or 2... I assume 

                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>

means Selenium 2 (but could obviously be wrong). If you know where can I find a good, clear, simple example abut maven running this tests (no HTMLsuite, it's JAVA) I would be grateful.

Thanks again!